# Does it make sense to use a gradient free optimizer within openmdao framework

Tags: openmdao

Is my understanding correct that : using a gradient free optimizer wraps the whole problem and treats it as a black box (even though the problem has multiple groups/components attached to inner solvers with gradients etc.).

Then the actual capabilities of openmdao are not exploited well and the advantage of openmdao boils down to easily tracking your calculations with smaller routines etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is true that OpenMDAO's most unique and powerful feature is its automatic derivatives capability, IMO that does not mean that it is only useful in the context of gradient based optimization. The framework offers several other features that are useful regardless of what optimizer you chose. For example:

- support for parallelization
- library of powerful nonlinear solvers
- modular model construction

You could certainly hand-code a large, complex model without OpenMDAO, then wrap that with a gradient free optimizer, but I would argue that you would ultimately end up doing a bit more work in the long run. Using a framework provides organization and structure to your model that pays off long term.